# Obtaining uniformly tight sequence of random variables from uniformly tight sequences via polynomials: two questions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random

Let $P:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}:= P(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{d}a_jx^j $ be a given non-zero polynomial of degree $d\ge 2.$

(1) Let $\{P(X_n)\}$ be a sequence of [uniformly tight random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380271/tightness-of-random-variables). N.B. (Uniformly) tight and stochastically bounded means the same thing. From here, can we in general infer that $\{X_n\}$ is also uniformly tight? If $P^{-1}$ exists and is unique, then it'll be continuous and so it'll map uniformly tight sequence to the same, but does the same argument hold for a general polynomial?

(2) Let $\alpha >0, \text{ and }  n^{\alpha}P(X_n)=O_P(1)$ (tight). Does this also mean  $n^{\alpha}{X_n}^{j}=O_P(1) \text{ (tight) } \forall 1\le j \le d$ ?

It seems to me that both, especially number (1) is true, but finding the precise argument seems to be difficult for me.

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, then there are constants $a,b > 0$ (depending only on the polynomial itself) such that $|P(x)| \ge a |x|^d - b$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$. Then, $ \mathbb P( |X_n| > M) = \mathbb P(a|X_n|^d - b> aM^d - b) \le \mathbb P ( |P(X_n)| > aM^d - b)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek Thank you - this settles the first question in the affirmative, but can it also be used to settle the second question in the affirmative? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think so. What if every $X_n$ is let's say $3$ almost surely and your polynomial is $P(x) = (x-3)^2$. Then $n^\alpha P(X_n) = 0$ a.s. so it's uniformly tight, but $n^\alpha X_n^j = n^\alpha 3^j$.